# Java Socket timeout exception read timeout

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, exception, timeout

I have got the following problem: 
my application has a logic like this: every time I make a change, I catch it and save to the Oracle XE 11g DB over my Webservice. It works fine for approximately first 20-30 times and then my client crashes with the following exception. The strange thing is that my server shows no exception but if I try to reconnect to it nothing works and I have to restart the server. I thought it might be because of not closed connections, so I run a thread to disconnect inactive connections and it does the work, but after 20-30 changes my application crashes again with still the same error. I am trying to find the place in code where I missed to close some resources, to put it clean, but if it were open connections, then the problem should be solved. What else could it be?

Thanks,
Jeff
Here is my error log:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.storeBinary(Unknown Source)
at biz.JB.database.resourceManager.core.ResourceManager.storeBinary(ResourceManager.java:522)
at edu.JB.projectmanager.resources.facade.MasterResourceManager.storeBinary(MasterResourceManager.java:787)
at edu.JB.projectmanager.resources.facade.ResourceOperationFacade.storeBinary(ResourceOperationFacade.java:625)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.util.FileUtil.saveDiagram(FileUtil.java:340)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.editor.PetriNetEditor$9.run(PetriNetEditor.java:713)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.editor.PetriNetEditor.doSave(PetriNetEditor.java:702)
at edu.JB.synchronization.handlers.SynchronizeClientsHandler$1.onPropertyChanged(SynchronizeClientsHandler.java:60)
at edu.JB.core.ui.EditorPropertyChangeHandler.handlePropertyChanged(EditorPropertyChangeHandler.java:39)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.editor.PetriNetEditor$2.propertyChanged(PetriNetEditor.java:506)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.firePropertyChange(WorkbenchPart.java:129)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.firePropertyChange(GraphicalEditor.java:201)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.editor.PetriNetEditor.commandStackChanged(PetriNetEditor.java:481)
at org.eclipse.gef.commands.CommandStack.notifyListeners(CommandStack.java:312)
at org.eclipse.gef.commands.CommandStack.execute(CommandStack.java:211)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCommand(AbstractTool.java:425)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCurrentCommand(AbstractTool.java:438)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.DragEditPartsTracker.performDrag(DragEditPartsTracker.java:496)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.DragEditPartsTracker.handleButtonUp(DragEditPartsTracker.java:351)
at edu.JB.editors.petrinets.parts.PetriNetDragEditPartsTracker.handleButtonUp(PetriNetDragEditPartsTracker.java:68)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.mouseUp(AbstractTool.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.SelectionTool.mouseUp(SelectionTool.java:574)
at org.eclipse.gef.EditDomain.mouseUp(EditDomain.java:301)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.DomainEventDispatcher.dispatchMouseReleased(DomainEventDispatcher.java:380)
at org.eclipse.draw2d.LightweightSystem$EventHandler.mouseUp(LightweightSystem.java:548)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at edu.karlsruhe.horus.core.Application.start(Application.java:73)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://******
: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1339)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1323)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1531)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
    ... 63 more
```